# Validate document file extension python

Tags: python

I'm working with Python 3, and I need to validate document files (such as *.pdf*, *.xlsx*, and *.docx*) that I get by request like a binary. I'm currently using a  little function that gets the hexa for the extension, but it only works with *.pdf*.

It looks like this:

```
def validate_binary_extension(self, file):
        extension = file[0:3].hex()
        extencions = ['255044', 'D0CF11', "D0CF11"]
        if  extension in extencions:
            return True
        else: 
            return False
```

I read the hexa for *.doc* and *.exe*, but I don't know how to get the extensions for those types of documents.

Comment: Side-note: The last four lines of this should really just be replaced with `return extension in extencions`; testing and return `True`/`False` is silly when the test itself is already producing `True`/`False`.

Comment: What is the "hexa for the extension"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes but i see that it is on the end for docx and exe

Comment: @ShadowRanger when get the first six hexa and dont'n match return false when i run unittest

Comment: @alejandrocorrea: I don't understand your last comment. I think you're telling me something about my last comment didn't work for you, but I'm not at all sure of that, let alone of what the problem is that I might fix.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It was not only me who had not understood your comment, thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious problem is that `.hex()` returns *lowercase* hex, and you provided uppercase hex constants. The first one would work because the hex is purely digits, but `'D0CF11'` should be `'d0cf11'` if you want it to match the output of `bytes.hex()`.

Comment: To be clear, none of those hex constants corresponds to a file extension of the ones you list, but I'm assuming you have some weird binary system that's not really a file *extension*. The misuse of the return from `.hex()` is at least an obvious problem with the logic.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to get the extension name, you could do:

```
def get_extension_name(filename):
    for index, char in enumerate(filename):
        if char == ".":
            return filename[index + 1:]
```

Comment: you'd better iterate from end to start to avoid getting `"bar.pdf"` as extension of `"foo.bar.pdf"`; otherwise, you can use somthing like `filename[-filename[::-1].find("."):]`

Comment: [`os.path.splitext` already exists to do precisely this, more reliably](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) (`str.rpartition` could be used with similar effect if imports are verboten for some homework assignment).

Comment: i'm not work with the path on system, only binary, so why i create a file when i get the request only to validate the extension and for save in other server?